# Video producer needs help capturing full motion screen casts on Android device

Tags: android, video-capture, tablet

I'm not a software developer, but I have done enough reading online to get the Android SDK, Eclipse, and the necessary downloads to get it all working.

I am able to capture device screenshots using the DDMS, but I need to capture full motion video of the system OS and apps for an Android TV commercial.

So far I've called the manufacturer and several software guys, but haven't had any luck.  I've even tried the HDMI out, but it's not pixel accurate, which is very important.

There has to be a way to do this, since the apps are featured in other commercials and videos, and I don't believe that the only way to do it is to film the device's screen.

No matter how complex the answer and solution to this might be, I'd love to find out.  Even if it means bringing on someone to execute it.

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

EDIT: It needs to be at least a 20-30 fps capture.

Answer (score 1):

Can't shoot the video then download it from the phone to your computer?  You are not being entirely clear about what you are trying to do exactly.

Are you trying to hook up a monitor to the phone, so you can view the camera live through the external monitor?

You might also want to try [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) for this question.

Also, [Android forums](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market?hl=en).

---

*EDIT*

Why didn't you just say so? ;)

- [Android USB VideoCapture using AndroidScreencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ePQJALdQWRk)
- [AndroidScreencast](http://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/)

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  What I need is to record what is happening ON the android device and save it as a quicktime file.  

Similarly to the screencast in this reddit video: http://www.reddit.com/iphone/ (on the right, not the youtube video)

Answer (score -2):

As of Android 4.4, there is a screen recording feature accessible via adb.

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#screenrecord

> The screenrecord command is a shell utility for recording the display of devices running Android 4.4 (API level 19) and higher. The utility records screen activity to an MPEG-4 file, which you can then download and use as part of a video presentation. This utility is useful for developers who want to create promotional or training videos without using a separate recording device.